# Make program able to run from terminal command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, symbolic-link, links

Having program in `/home/user/Downloads/program/main`

I can launch it by following command `cd /home/user/Downloads/program && ./main` or from GUI.

What I want is to launch it from terminal by typing `main`
I tried to do `ln -s /home/user/Downloads/program/main /usr/local/bin` or to `/bin` but it had no effect.

Before linking I issued `chmod +x` command.

This is compiled program, error message I get is `main: command not found`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error message when you try to run the program? And is it a script, or a compiled program?

Comment: @NathanShiraini, compiled program, message `main: command not found`

Comment: Theorically you just have to `chmod +x` it and put it or a link to it in a folder in your PATH. To see these folders, run the command `echo $PATH`.

Comment: already did this. I thought I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `ls -al /home/user/Downloads/program/main`, to verify permissions?

Comment: Add a function to your .bashrc file to do this like; `function x() {/home/.../main $1}` or before run your program, paste this to your terminal and use it until you close terminal. Run it as `x options ` if you don't need to use options just type `x`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add that directory to your path. The exact command to do this depends on which shell is in use. For bash, you'll need something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Downloads/program/
```

Explanation:

- The PATH=$PATH keeps the existing path as part of the new path your are creating.
- The :/home/user/Downloads/program/ adds that directory to the path (at the end, so it is the last thing searched).
- The export puts the path in the shell so that it stays there. You might not need that part for a single session. However, if you want to keep this in future login sessions, you'll want to add this to your .bashrc (or other file that gets executed when you login).

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new program to the path, you need to type

```
rehash
```

For it to be known to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

As a fast fix you can make an alias. Add to you `~/.bashrc` file this:

```
alias main='/home/user/Downloads/program/./main'
```

then run `exec bash` in your terminal and it should work. If you're not using bash something similar would work for other shells. For example writing to the file `~/.zshrc` for the `zsh` shell.